# Functions/Methods and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, function, methods

My class has just started learning how to write code in a format with functions and methods, and this is my first attempt at it - I feel like I'm just confusing myself.

The assignment is to create a pool of numbers 1 to a randomly selected number and to store the pool in an array; then print the pool; then a user selects a number from the pool, and the program finds the divisors of that number and stores them in another array that will then be printed.

I am having problems with getting the divisors, storing them in a new array and then printing the array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class GetDivisors {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);            
        int     []pool = new int[100];
        int     []divisors = new int[100];
        int     size;
        int     pick;
        int     numDivisor;

        // Program Heading
    printProgramHeading();

        // Input and test
    size = createPool(pool);
    printPool(pool, size);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
    pick=read.nextInt();

        // Data Processing
    numDivisor = getDivisors(pool, divisors, pick);

        // Output Section
    printDivisors(divisors, size, pick);    

    } // end main

        // Function and Method Specifications
    // Name         : printProgramHeading
    // Description  : This method prints the program heading to the monitor in all caps and with     a dividing line
    //              : followed by a blank line.
    // Parameters   : None.
    // Return       : None.
    public static void printProgramHeading() {
        System.out.println("\tGET DIVISORS");
        System.out.println("  ************************");
        System.out.println();
    } // end printHeading


    //Name          : createPool
    //Description   : This funtion generates an array of consecutive integers from 1 to a randomly     generated
    //              : number no greater than 100.
    //Parameters    : An integer array.
    //Return        : An integer (the randomly generated number), representing the size of the array.
    public static int createPool(int[]pool) {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Random random = new Random();
        int size=0;

        size=random.nextInt(100)+1;
        pool=new int[size];

        return(size);
    } // end createPool


    //Name          : printPool
    //Description   : This method prints the pool of numbers to the monitor no more than 10 per line.
    //Parameters    : The pool array, and the size of the pool in that order.
    //Return        : None.
    public static void printPool(int[] pool, int size) { 
        int index;
        int count=0;

        for(index=1; index<size; index++){
            System.out.print(pool[index]=index);
            System.out.print(" ");
            count++;
            if(count == 10){
                System.out.println();
                count=0;
            } // end if loop
        } // end for loop
    } // end printPool


    //Name          : getDivisors
    //Description   : This funtion stores all the divisors of the user's pick into the divisor array.
    //Parameters    : The pool array, the divisor array, and the user's pic, in that order.
    //Return        : The number of divisors found.
    public static int getDivisors(int[] pool, int[] divisors, int pick){
        int numDivisors = 0;
        int index = 0;

        for(index=1; index <= pick; index++){
            if(pick % index == 0){
                numDivisors++;
                divisors[index] = index;
            } // end if loop
        } // end for loop
        return(numDivisors);
    } // end getDivisors


    //Name          : printDivisors
    //Description   : This method prints the contents of the divisors array to the monitor all on one line with
    //              : a leading label.
    //Parameters    : The divisor array, an integer representing the number of divisors. and the     user's pick
    //              : in that order.
    //Return        : None.
    public static void printDivisors(int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
        int index = 0;

        System.out.println("The divisors of " + pick + ": " + divisors[index] + " ");
    } // end printDivisors

} // end class
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try to describe what exactly you expect your `for` loop in `getDivisors()` to accomplish.

Comment: To get the divisors, start at the beginning of the pool and go up to the number that the user picked. If the number picked divided by the pool number has a remainder of 0, then that pool number is a divisor - then I need to store it in an array that I can print in the next step, which is where I am getting stuck. When I try to run the program and print the divisors, I just get 0 instead of the list of divisors.

Comment: You never assign any values to any element of your newly created arrays (`divisors`).

Comment: **Most** of your methods do not do what, according to your comments, you expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a school project. In order for you to learn I don't want to give you the answers but i'll point out your mistakes, so that you can fix your problems.

**First in this method createPool:**

```
//Name          : createPool
//Description   : This funtion generates an array of consecutive integers from 1 to a randomly     generated
//              : number no greater than 100.
//Parameters    : An integer array.
//Return        : An integer (the randomly generated number), representing the size of the array.
public static int createPool(int[]pool) {
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in); 
    Random random = new Random();
    int size=0;

    size=random.nextInt(100)+1;
    pool=new int[size];

    return(size);
} // end createPool
```

Look closer at the values that are stored in the array.

**Second in method printPool:**

```
//Name          : printPool
//Description   : This method prints the pool of numbers to the monitor no more than 10 per line.
//Parameters    : The pool array, and the size of the pool in that order.
//Return        : None.
public static void printPool(int[] pool, int size) { 
    int index;
    int count=0;

    for(index=1; index<size; index++){
        System.out.print(pool[index]=index);
        System.out.print(" ");
        count++;
        if(count == 10){
            System.out.println();
            count=0;
        } // end if loop
    } // end for loop
} // end printPool
```

You are updating the values of the pool. This method should only print the values in the pool. You should be setting the values of the pool in createPool, and printing the values of the pool in printPool.

**Next in the getDivisors method**

```
//Name          : getDivisors
//Description   : This funtion stores all the divisors of the user's pick into the divisor array.
//Parameters    : The pool array, the divisor array, and the user's pic, in that order.
//Return        : The number of divisors found.
public static int getDivisors(int[] pool, int[] divisors, int pick){
    int num = 0;
    int divisor = 0;
    int numDivisors = 0;
    int index = 0;

for(pool[index]=1; pool[index]<=pick; pool[index]){
    num = pick % pool[index];
    if(num == 0){
        divisor = num;
        numDivisors++;
        divisors= new int[divisor];
    } // end if loop
} // end for loop
return(numDivisors);
} // end getDivisors
```

You have a lot of things wrong with this method. First, re-look at your for loop. I really think you need to learn further about how for loop should operate and when is the best time for use for loops. Your underlying understanding of for loops in flawed. Your logic is right for calculating the divisor, but you have two issues related to this logic. 1) Relook at how you put the new `divisor` into the `divisors` array. This is related to the earlier issue of how you use the for loop. Once you solve the for loop problem, this should become more clear 2) What should you store into the `divisors` array when `num == 0` is **false**? You need to handle this case, right?

**Now onto the printDivisors method:**

```
//Name          : printDivisors
//Description   : This method prints the contents of the divisors array to the monitor all on one line with
//              : a leading label.
//Parameters    : The divisor array, an integer representing the number of divisors. and the     user's pick
//              : in that order.
//Return        : None.
public static void printDivisors(int[] divisors, int size, int pick){
    int index = 0;

    System.out.println("The divisors of " + pick + ": " + divisors[index] + " ");
} // end printDivisors
```

Once again, you really need to understand when and when-not to use a for loop. This method should print out **all** the values in the `divisors` array. Currently, this method only prints out one value in the `divisors` array (the first value, at index 0).

**Finally, in the main() function:**

```
public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);            
        int     []pool = new int[100];
        int     []divisors = new int[100];
        int     size;
        int     pick;
        int     divisor;

        // Program Heading
    printProgramHeading();

        // Input and test
    size = createPool(pool);
    printPool(pool, size);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
    pick=read.nextInt();

        // Data Processing
    divisor = getDivisors(pool, divisors, pick);

        // Output Section
    printDivisors(divisors, size, pick);    

    } // end main
```

Should int[] pool, and int[] divisors be initialized initially with an arbitrary size of 100? Random numbers like these are usually called "magic numbers". Magic numbers should either be set as a constant with a description, or taken out of the program. Next, you print the header. This seems ok. Then you create the pool, and save the pool size into `size`, and print the pool with the given `size` passed into the function. This all seems fine. Next you poll the user for a divisor input, and call the `getDivisors` function with the user input. Also you save the output into a variable `divisor`, which represent the size of the divisor array. **Now, look at the parameters you pass into `printDivisors`**, something smells fishy here...

These are all of the issues that I see with your code. This should give you plenty of information on how to improve your mistakes. If you have anymore questions please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment your question. Is it ok if you use Collections instead of arrays?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetDivisorsRefactored {

    private static Integer[] pool;
    private static Scanner read;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Program Heading
        printProgramHeading();
        initPool();
        System.out.println("Available list: ");
        printArray(pool);

        read = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter a non-prime value listed in the pool above: ");
        int pick=read.nextInt();        
        Integer[] divisors = findDivisors(pick);;
        printArray(divisors);
    }

    private static void printArray(Integer[] someArray) {
        int nextRow = 0;
        for (int num: someArray){           
                System.out.printf("%4d,", num);
                if (++nextRow > 9){
                    System.out.println();
                    nextRow =0;
                }
        }

    }

    private static Integer[] findDivisors(int pick) {
        List<Integer> divisors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int index = 1; index < pool.length; index++){
            if ((pick % pool[index]) == 0){
                divisors.add(pool[index]);
            }
        }
        return divisors.toArray(new Integer[divisors.size()]);
    }

    private static void initPool() {
        int size = (int) (Math.random()*100) + 1;
        pool = new Integer[size];
        for (int index = 0; index < pool.length; index++){
            pool[index] = index;            
        }

    }   

    // Function and Method Specifications
    // Name : printProgramHeading
    // Description : This method prints the program heading to the monitor in
    // all caps and with a dividing line
    // : followed by a blank line.
    // Parameters : None.
    // Return : None.
    public static void printProgramHeading() {
        System.out.println("\tGET DIVISORS");
        System.out.println("  ************************");
        System.out.println();
    } // end printHeading

}
```